# WP website showing blank page after moving from subdomain to main domain

Tags: database, migration, phpmyadmin, fatal-error

I created my website on the subfolder https://www.lokaction.be/dev/.

After it was finished, I moved the website's files to the main adress https://www.lokaction.be/ (ftp). And after that, I edited the `siteurl` and `home` record in the database in the `wp_options` table.

I have done this before, and as far as i rememeber, these were all the steps that were needed. However, as you can see for yourself, nothing is showing, just a blank page. Also no connection error, the page source is blank too.

What happened? What could be the cause? The only difference with other websites I moved is that I installed the Wordfence plugin. Could this be a problem? And mostly, were do i start to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you turn on the debug log via wp-config.php?
https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#WP_DEBUG

Comment: Done, debug is now active.

Comment: Does the .htaccess mention the subfolder (eg in the `RewriteBase` line)?

Comment: It does, but changing it from /dev/ to / didn't change anything either. Something else i can try?

Comment: Log file is available in `website_root/htdocs/wp-content/debug.log` Can you check the file if you see anything in there? Because you seem to be getting a server 500 error. So that's probably because of your webserver or some of the code is creating a fatal error.

Comment: Debug is on (define('WP_DEBUG', true); define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);) Yet, there is no debug.log in the content map. I think the website doesn't even get to the point of logging errors?

Comment: There normally are webserver (nginx, apache, etc.) logs as well as PHP server (FastCGI, PHP-FPM) logs available. One knows what's going on. You should also look through your `php-fpm.conf` and `/php-fpm.d/*.conf` PHP-FPM config files to find your log location. Maybe you are looking at the wrong folder and therefore it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

you need to see below post to move word-press site one server to other

Ref :- [Wordpress link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

some simple steps follow and change site location

you can update your database using following queries

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'https://www.oldurl', 'https://www.newurl') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'https://www.oldurl','https://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'https://www.oldurl', 'https://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'https://www.oldurl','https://www.newurl');
```

Comment: I followed Moving Directories On Your Existing Server untill step 9. But i can't login or anything since the website appears to be gone. In the database, the url's in the guid field in wp_posts still contain the /dev/-part of the url. But i don't think editing them here will do much good?

Comment: use mysql to update you new location

Comment: I just used the 4 queries correctly, however, the website is still showing a blank page. This is really weird!

Comment: old url: https://www.lokaction.be/dev/ new url: https://www.lokaction.be/. I checked that the old url was the one used in the database everywhere, so it should be correct.

Comment: you moved your project outer of dev

Comment: Yes, all files are in the main location for the domain. I also checked this map works by adding an index.html file and this file did show up. However, nothing from wordpress' index.php file at all when i delete index.html again

Comment: now we have one way download you wp-content folder and export database than add new wordpress and put all in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82463/discussion-between-dev-ramiz-1707-and-kevin-verhoeven).

Comment: Okay, i'm new to this website so i hope chat is available for me.